# CentOS - Hostname showing as my hosting provider, not server

Tags: dns, ping, hostname, traceroute

I've recently purchased a new server, it's set up and configured with CentOS 5.7 and cPanel/WHM.

DNS resolves correctly when accessing websites that point to the server, however, there is a problem when I ping/traceroute.

For Example sake; my hostname is `host.example.com`

But when I do a traceroute on any of my domains pointing to this host/directly to the IP of the server, it returns this:

```
1     0       0       0          206.123.64.42    -  

2     0       0       0          173.219.246.92  173-219-246-92-link.sta.suddenlink.net  
3     31      31      31         66.76.30.29     tyrmcrs01-10gex0-6-0-2.tex.sta.suddenlink.net  
4     30      30      30         66.76.232.13    66-76-232-13.tyrd.suddenlink.net  
5     37      37      39         66.76.232.6     chicosrc01-10gex1-1.tex.sta.suddenlink.net  
6     134     131     134        206.223.119.124     320.e1-1.cr1.ord0.amcbb.net  
7     151     162     174        x.x.x.x     ve769.cr.x.x.net  
8     200     200     204        x.x.x.x     x.ge-0-1.x.x.x.net  
9     199     199     191        x.x.x.x     x.x.x.x.net
(IP removed & Hostname's x'd for privacy)
```

The hostname for my server is now appearing as `x.x.x.x.net` (ie; not my servers hostname)

Also, when I'm using Pingdom's tools, Both their ping/traceroute testers are returning "Invalid hostname" - which I'm guessing is because of this.

**I've changed resolver.conf - used the system-config-network tool - checked the hosts file**

What do I need to do to set the hostname correctly?
Is this something I need to contact my provider about?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN PTR RR in `in-addr.arpa` zone for your IP must be changed to reflect your hostname (if it's your personal IP). This changes can be done by network-range owner only

PS - there aren't any privacy/security leaks in publishing IP-address and|or your hostname

Comment: I see, so I'll have to contact my hosting provider? - I know, I just don't want to be DOS'd :)

Comment: @Moe - yes, you have to